# How scientific are the Prilepin tables?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises

Are the prilepin tables like this one http://www.eatmoveimprove.com/2012/05/prilepin-tables-for-bodyweight-strength-isometric-and-eccentric-exercises/ attested by scientists? Or are they just someone's best guess?

If it's relevant, I am using this table to tell me how long to do planks for and how many reps to do.

Can't hold the plank for much more than 6s at the moment, so it says I should do 6 reps...

Comment: Interesting article. I'm afraid I don't know enough to answer your question, but thank you for the pointer.

Comment: Agreed. I had not heard of Prilepin before, but I don't believe he did it as studies, he merely incorporated studies/recommendations of the day (late 70's/early 80's) into a cohesive program. It's more of an experience at the time type of compilation. And, while the list of records is impressive, this was also during the heyday of steroids and other performance enhancers in the the Eastern Bloc.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google brings up: [Evaluating Common Weight Training Concepts Associated With Developing Muscular Strength: Truths or Myths?](http://www.goodlift.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Evaluating_Common_Weight_Training_Concepts.15.pdf) which on bottom of page 92 states:

> Powerlifting is not considered a power sport; however, several individuals in
>   the sport of powerlifting promote the implementation of a power training
>   program developed by a former U.S.S.R. weightlifting coach Prilepin (37).
>
> The Prilepin chart, which has proven to be a successful strategy for
>   improving muscular power, was developed specifically for the sport of
>   weightlifting.  In the sport of weightlifting, force and velocity of execution
>   depends on the load; therefore, selection of the appropriate load is vital for
>   developing the required muscle quality (e.g., strength, endurance, or power).
>   The influence of maximal isometric strength on dynamic force and velocity
>   is greater in high-load slow movements often observed in powerlifting; 
>   therefore, a correlation between maximal velocity and maximal strength has not
>   been shown to exist (36).

And cites a couple of further papers, so there appears to be some peer reviewed research to support them eg.

36. Zatsiorsky VM. Biomechanical foundations of strength and power training. In:
    Biomechanics in Sport: Performance Enhancement and Injury Prevention: Olympic
    Encyclopaedia of Sports Medicine. Vol IX. Zatsiorsky VM, ed. Malden, MA: Wiley Blackwell,2000. pp. 103–113.
37. Zatsiorsky VM and Kraemer WJ. TaskSpecific Strength. In: Science and Practice
    of Strength Training. Zatsiorsky VM and Kraemer WJ, eds. Champaign, IL: Human
    Kinetics, 2006. 18–33.

Comment: Rather than just a link, perhaps you could cite the relevant content of the papers you mention? As it is, this is a single unsupported sentence.